# What need install to use mvc 6 in vs2017

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017

Following this steps to use mvc6 show how to use some templates

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37549.asp-net-mvc-6-in-visual-studio-2017-basics.aspx

[image]

But my visual studio only have ASP.NET Core, not .Net Framework.

[image]

So which one need to install to have ASP.Net  with .NET Framework?

My guess is one of this 2:

- Development Universal Windows Platform
- Development Multiplatform .NET Core

[image]

Comment: Universal Windows Platform is nothing to do with ASP.NET

Comment: @ADyson Ok, but that doesnt help to solve my problem. As I said was a guess.

Comment: I know it doesn't solve anything directly, hence just a comment and not an answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

After selecting ASP.Net Core Web Application a template selector will come up where you should be able to switch the framework in the upper left corner:
[image]

Hope it is what you are looking for!